# Where's the Steam setting to change the input device for my headset?

Tags: steam

I've been trying to get into the Steam settings to change the input device for my headset so I won't have to use external software for VOIP,  but for some reason, I had the biggest brain fart and cannot find it in the upper toolbar.

[image: (This is what I mean)]

Did Valve move it in a new update? I participate in the beta versions of Steam when available, but I thought it was perfect just where it was so I doubt they would have moved it. Any ideas on where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got a SE account. I just saw you post and I've actually had this problem before. Though, I was trying to get into the Steam Store. You see, recently I bought a game off a sketchy website and I thought. "hmm, I shouldn't have done that" so I changed my password and added a parental lock, which requires a PIN to use the store, or any potentially harming settings. Anyway, it's really unobvious at first, but in top right corner on your steam page is a green button that looks like two white people doing the "shadow" pose in front of a green screen. Just click it, enter in the most familiar 4-digit PINs you can think of, and eventually it should unlock for you. Hope this helps and see you at the next WP practice!

Comment: Hey! That worked! Thanks big "J". I'm sorry, I actually quit WP so I won't see you until PROM. Though, we could still play on steam. What's your user?

Comment: Oh, okay; that's a shame. I'll text you my user. :)